# SSRS 2019 Run All Reports That Use the Same Shared Schedule

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

During database maintenance, we want to disable a shared report schedule that occurs during this time.

When we enable the shared schedule, how can we run all the reports that should have run during the downtime?

How can we stop reports from running during a downtime and then run the missed reports after?

Comment: You could temporarily change the shared schedule to make the reports run after the downtime and then restore to its default settings

Comment: That seems like a good solution, thank you.